# EF Core - Recreate Single Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a process where I'm trying to keep a database up to date from a bunch of CSV's that are updated. Basically, the plan is to have triggers that watch a github repo and process csv's when a new commit hits master.

Right now, I'm hitting a wall with dropping a table before recreating it. I am able to drop all tables and then recreate all the tables. However, I need the ability to drop a single table (easy) and then recreate the table so it's empty and I can upload the new csv into it. Is there a way to do this?

```
await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AllStarFull");
await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Appearances");
var dbCreator = (RelationalDatabaseCreator) context.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>();
await dbCreator.CreateTablesAsync(); // Wishing there was a method to create a SINGLE table here...
```

Ideally, I'd want something like this:

```
var dbCreator = (RelationalDatabaseCreator) context.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>();
await dbCreator.CreateTableAsync(Model);
```

I know I can easily run the same `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` with the sql required to create the table, but I think that goes against the EF Framework. Unless there's some sort of way to get the generated sql from a given entity framework model.

Comment: Not sure, but why not just truncate the table instead of drop and recreate?

Comment: Haven't thought about truncating yet. Would truncate reset the identity column as well? My main two concerns is duplicate data (I'm essentially just re-uploading a csv that may or may not have changed) and making sure my identity column is reset on a new upload (starts with Id  = 1)

Comment: I think using csv files in a remote github repo for database maintenance is against the EF framework, so using sql required to create and drop the table should be least of your concerns.

Comment: Meh. That's just like, your opinion, man.

Comment: Yes, Truncate resets identity (assuming SQL Server for dbms). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, @Ben.

Comment: While all these comments provide a workaround to the OP, it doesn't actually answer the issue at hand (which I'm also facing) which is the need to recreate a SINGLE table. My reason is that I've added some new columns but I also have data in other tables that I don't want to lose. `dbCreator.CreateTablesAsync();` only provides a way to recreate all or none (and none being throwing an exception) which is far from ideal.

Comment: FWIW: I went with the truncate approach.